# Test button is disabled

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can i check that this button is disabled:

```
<button _ngcontent-c8="" class="customButton" testid="save-button" type="submit"><span _ngcontent-c8="" class="textButtonForm"> Sauver </span></button>
```

I have tested:

```
cy.getBySel('save-button').should('have.attr', 'disabled')
Even tested:
cy.getBySel('save-button').should('be.disabled')
```

i have the error:

```
expected <button.customButton.formNotChanged> to have attribute disabled
```

Any advice pls?

Comment: is this the exact dom? how does it look like when it is enabled?

Comment: Looks like your element is disabled through a parent element. You should find out what is changing when it is changed from enabled to disabled or vice versa. that will give us an idea about what to look for to check about the state.

Comment: Based on the HTML you posted there is no `disabled` attribute. So that is why the test fails. You have to first set the button in disabled state I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If that is how the element looks at runtime, you can just add the square brackets to make it work.

```js
cy.getBySel('save-button').should('have.attr', '[disabled]')
```

However, I think you are showing the **source code** not the **runtime HTML**.

This `[disabled]="myFormForm.invalid"` says whenever the form is invalid, add the `disabled` attribute.

So, in your test you need to cause the form to be invalid. Then both test examples you gave will work.

Look at the other fields in the form and see what validations are set up. The simplest would be a `required` validation - make sure that element is empty.

Comment: sorry i have added the DOM..I wrongly pasted the code.. I have modified it now

Comment: Could you please also add the other fields in the form. I think the key to doing this is to make sure one of those fields is invalid, but need to find out what that would be.

Comment: i see this difference in code when it gets disabled and not disabled:
when its disabled:
```
<form _ngcontent-c8="" class="b4 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" novalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]"><div _ngco<form _ngcontent-c8="" class="b4 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" novalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
```
when enabled
```
<form _ngcontent-c8="" class="b4 ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-dirty ng-touched" novalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
```
I tried to post the form html but it is saying its too long

Comment: No problem - you can manually check the input fields on the page, if you click in the field, leave it empty and click away there should be a red invalid message like "The field is required". That should make the button get the `disabled` attribute. If you can find that input, I can give you the test code to make it work.

Comment: <form _ngcontent-c8="" class="b4 ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-dirty ng-touched" novalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">

<input _ngcontent-c8="" class="marge-input inputCustom ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-touched" formcontrolname="firstname" type="text" ng-reflect-name="firstname">
<div _ngcontent-c8="" class="error ng-star-inserted">This field is required</div>

<button _ngcontent-c8="" class="customButton" id="save-button" type="submit" disabled=""><span _ngcontent-c8="" class="textButtonForm"> Sauver </span></button>

I have got the above.

Comment: Ok cool, see now the button has the disabled attribute! I will write the tests code, but you probably already guessed what it would be.

Comment: yes..i can pick up from here.Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @Fody
Hoping you can help me here :)
i have to activate the disabled attribute here:
<div _ngcontent-c19="" class="button button-test-mail ng-star-inserted" testid="button-disabled"> My test mail </div>

This is part of the form one field:
<input _ngcontent-c19="" id="subject" name="subject" ng-reflect-name="subject" placeholder="title class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">

Thank you

Comment: If you want to test the button gets disabled when the input is invalid, this should do it - `cy.get('input[id="subject"]').focus().blur()` that's like the user clicking into then away from the input. Then as you have above `cy.getBySel('save-button').should('be.disabled')` should now pass.

Comment: You can also add test for the error message itself `cy.contains('div.error', 'This field is required').should('be.visible')`.

Comment: Actually the error message This field is required does not show at all in any cases..
if the fields are empty the buttons are enabled else it is disabled.
i tried this "cy.get('input[id="subject"]').focus().blur()" but it did not trigger the disabled..

Comment: Actually, `'input[id="subject"]'` is the Title field, which often is allowed to be empty. Try with firstname - `cy.get('input[formcontrolname="firstname"]').focus().blur()`. First thing to do for this test (IMO) is find out all the validation checks that can make the form invalid, then trigger them one by one and each time check the button is disabled. So, `.focus().blur()` should work for `required` fields, but maybe there are other validations.

Comment: At the end i did:
cy.getBySel('button-disabled').should('not.be.enabled') and it worked